# Sql Injection ByPass problem

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I don't know what if part of this command does.

````
FROM   table 
WHERE  id = 1 
       AND IF(( Ascii(Lower(Substring((SELECT User()), $i, 1))) ) != $s, 1, 
               Benchmark(200000, Md5(Now()))) ```

any one can help me?
````

Comment: You need to paste the full code, no one knows what $i and $s are. Benchmark always returns 0 so I would guess that’s just to generate some load on the server for some reason. On a test DB I need to add two 0’s to it to make it take longer than a second however.

Comment: last line: They're calculating the checksum of the current timestamp about 200,000 times

Comment: @Gaius Yes i know it should make some load, but i don't understand what this code does  clearly.
why we don't use sleep instead?

Comment: @tungsten Ooook got it :) tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other folks are mentioning, it would be good to understand the context of the code a bit more.  But this looks like SQL that has a blind SQL payload appended into it (presumably via a SQL injection).  In this case, the SQL + payload is using a timing attack that is intended to pause for a long time in the case of a character match and quickly otherwise.

It is probably used in a loop which iterates through the characters to determine a value in the DB - in this case User().  The *$i* is the character position in the string being determined - the *$s* is the current letter being tested.

For more information on this type of timing attack see the time-based section of the [OWASP Blind SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Blind_SQL_Injection) page.

Comment: *"It is probably used in a loop which iterates through the characters to determine a value in the DB"* More or less i assume that cracking code to be a bit *"smarter"* most likely this is used in the combination with a [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to make lesser requests for the brute forcing a character within the A to Z range could be found then anywhere between 1 (very lucky case) and 13 tries instead off 26 tries ..

Comment: Good point - yes, the hackers would be smart to be using a binary search algorithm.  The interesting question is could they do better than log(n) by using an interpolation search which leveraged common letter patterns :-)

Comment: yes assuming they have a common username / password list or a *"Pwned"* password list they also could use that instead possibly optimize `log(n)` into  common letter patterns or get a direct match offcource..